# how to change SetFrame Rate in Camera plugin?

Tags: gazebo-camera

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

in my camera plugin,I use this method "camera->SetRenderRate(30)"and"SaveFrame()"

but,the frame rate is really slow(http://ppt.cc/Xdzp)

how can I save  30 frame per second?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8361/how-to-change-setframe-rate-in--camera-plugin?/) by [Zheng yo chen](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/800/zheng-yo-chen/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 80 on 2015-04-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Saving frames to disk will be slow. Gazebo has to pull information off the graphics card, convert it to a png, then dump the information to disk. A smaller image will be faster.

We have improved rendering, but this won't be released until Gazebo6 in July of this year. You can try it out by compiling Gazebo from source.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2015-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0